# Can you use Regex but keep formatting?

Tags: c#, html, regex, formatting, pdfsharp

I have this line of code that allows me to remove the HTML tags that were displaying in my text but it loses all the formatting. And I am wondering if there is anyway to remove the HTML tags but keep the formatting of the text, like bold, italic and so on. Here is the line of code:

```
 report.Description = Regex.Replace(report.Description, "<.*?>|&nbsp;", string.Empty);
```

Here is the line of code that is displaying the description field:

```
        graphics.DrawString("" + report.Description, font2, XBrushes.Black, new XRect(margin, page.Height - (lineHeight * 35), page.Width, page.Height), XStringFormats.TopCenter);
```

I also have this public class in my reports.cs file:

```
  public string Description { get; set; }
```

I am using PDFsharp to get this to display in a PDF. 
Any advice or support would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Which language is this? c#?

Comment: yes c# in an mvc 4 project using visual studio thank u

Comment: Some background information about the question can be found here:  http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2792   adandrea808 needs a string with plain text only and also needs an Font object that reflects the HTML tags that were removed. The question is misleading as the formatting is not to be kept in the string.

Comment: is there any somewhat easy solution to allow my text to be displayed with its proper formatting or will I only be able to display plain text?? im not sure if there is somehwere else in my code that is causing this issue or if this a pdfsharp feature that doesnt allow it to display properly? any more help would be really appreciated. thank u in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds much like a filter one might create to protect against cross site scripting attacks.  The idea is to keep a subset of HTML elements considered safe or desirable and discard all others.

Several forms of **Regex.Replace** accept a **MatchEvaluator** delegate that is called each time a regular expression match is found.  The logic to keep certain elements can be implemented within the delegate.

The following class may meet your needs.

```
public static class HtmlFilter
{
    private static HashSet<string> _keep;

    static HtmlFilter()
    {
        _keep = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        _keep.Add("b");
        _keep.Add("em");
        _keep.Add("i");
        _keep.Add("span");
        _keep.Add("strong");
        // Add other tags as needed.
    }

    private static string ElementFilter(Match match)
    {
        string tag = match.Result("${tag}");

        if (_keep.Contains(tag))
            return match.Value;
        else
            return string.Empty;
    }

    public static string Apply(string input)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"</?(?<tag>\w*)[^>]*>|&nbsp;");
        return regex.Replace(input, new MatchEvaluator(ElementFilter));
    }
}
```

You can then filter your report description using:

```
report.Description = HtmlFilter.Apply(report.Description);
```

Note that the regular expression keeps the HTML attributes so that formatting elements like `<span style="...">` are preserved.

Comment: Unfortunately Joel this didnt work, it just returned the description with all the tags included in the text display. Was there anything I was supposed to modify? or do you have any other ideas on how to keep formatting but remove all tags from being displayed? thanks so much

Comment: This solution works only if `report.Description` is HTML source.  If the HTML tags appear in the rendered HTML (your display text), it likely means that the angle brackets surrounding the tags are already escaped as &lt; and &gt; in the HTML source.  If that's the case, then modifying your original regular expression to match the escaped form may work.

Comment: in my mvc model i have this code and that is where the description field comes from. I am assuming it is html.      
    public class Reports
    {      
        public string Description { get; set; }

Comment: joel, can you give me a little more info on what "modifying your original regular expression to match the escaped form" this entails please. i got no tags displaying with my first regex code but i just need to allow some formatting to show up.

Comment: Maybe something like "&lt;.*?&gt;|&nbsp;" would work for you.

Comment: still no luck. i wondering if there is another solution besides using regex? any ideas joel ?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the actual value of `report.Description` that you are testing with.

Comment: I updated the question to add more detail. when using the code example above joel provided i can still see all the tags, but when using my regex.replace i still the text but no formatting is showing up. any more advice would really help. thank u.